# How to deserialize JSON object into an interface TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, fetch

```js
const response = await fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy/?quest=http://hamsterland.herokuapp.com/api/users?id=330746772378877954');
const json = await response.json(); 
const user: User = JSON.parse(json);
```

```js
interface User {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    avatar: string;
}
```

On the last line, `JSON.parse(json)`, I receive an error that states:

```
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

I am not sure what is causing this. The interface model matches the JSON structure.

Comment: It's already parsed.  That's what `.json()` does.

Comment: https://paste.mod.gg/akepubiwix.json @Nonik

Comment: The error you are seeing is because you are trying to parse an already parsed json string.  So when you run `JSON.parse(object)` it has to try to figure out what to do, so it to strings the object which turns into `JSON.parse('[object Object]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `JSON.parse(json)` was unnecessary. All I had to do was

```js
const response = await fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy/?quest=http://hamsterland.herokuapp.com/api/users?id=330746772378877954');
const user: User = await response.json();
```

Thank you @Taplar for the solution.